# NewRelic thinks I have DelayedJob installed, but I don't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, newrelic

I used to have delayed job but since I have removed it from my `Gemfile`.

I have included today the `newrelic_rpm` gem and run `bundle install`.
Since then I can't start my server and I get the following nasty error stack:

```
 /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- delayed_job (LoadError)
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `const_get'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/queue_adapter.rb:31:in `load_adapter'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/queue_adapter.rb:23:in `queue_adapter='
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:18:in `each'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/base.rb:66:in `<class:Base>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/base.rb:56:in `<module:ActiveJob>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activejob-4.2.4/lib/active_job/base.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:74:in `call'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:74:in `block in execute'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:72:in `execute'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:30:in `block in detect!'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:28:in `each'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:28:in `detect!'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/control/instrumentation.rb:65:in `_install_instrumentation'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/control/instrumentation.rb:48:in `install_instrumentation'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/new_relic/control/instance_methods.rb:73:in `init_plugin'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.0.299/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/nitrous/my_app/.bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it,

I'll post the answer here if someone is encountering the same issue

Removing `delayed_job` from the `Gemfile` isn't enough.
As seen in the documentation: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job , you have to delete the corresponding `db:migrate` task (or revert it), as well as edit your `application.rb` file to remove the following line:(if using Rails 4.2)

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```